# Capturing FORM values to update in POST

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have an HTML form in a servlet with several input parms, when I press the Submit button, I want to take the values from the form and write those to a file. I am not certain how to capture the parms to be used in the next .jsp. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class CreateCust extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    // Generate a Customer Account using the Random Number Generator
    // Calculate Confirmation Number
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int custNum = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
    String custId = "CST" + custNum;

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Customer Profile Information";
    String MainPageURL =
          response.encodeURL("/csj/CustomerAccounts.html");
    String docType =
      "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
      "Transitional//EN\">\n";
    out.println(docType +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                "<H1 ALIGN=\"CENTER\">" + title + "</H1>");

    out.println("<BR>" +
        "<BR>" +
        "<a href=" + MainPageURL + ">Previous Page</a>");  

        out.println
          ("<Form>\n" +   
          "<CENTER>" +
            "Please Enter the following Information:\n" +

            "<TABLE border=1>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Customer ID: " +  
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Label>" + custId + " </Label>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Name:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_name\" </input>\n" +
            "</TR>" +

            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Street Address:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Add1\" </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Apt or Suite:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Add2\" </input>\n" + 
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "City:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_City\" </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "State:" +
            "</TD><TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_state\" </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Zip Code:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Zip\" </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Phone Number:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
             "<Input type=\"Text\" name=\"F_Phone\" </input>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Cable Plan:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<select>\n" +
                "<option value=\"selcab\">Select Cable</option>\n" +
                "<option value=\"Basic50\">Basic50</option>\n" +
                "<option value=\"Basic100\">Basic100</option>\n" +
                "<option value=\"Ultimate200\">Ultimate200</option>\n" +
            "</select>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<BR>" +
            "<TR><TD>" +
            "Internet Plan:" +
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<select>\n" +
                "<option value=\"selInt\">Select Internet</option>\n" +
                "<option value=\"speedlane\">SpeedLane</option>\n" +
                "<option value=\"lightlane\">LightLane</option>\n" +
            "</select>\n" +
            "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<TABLE>" +


            "</CENTER>" +
            "</Form>"  );




        String confirmURL =
          response.encodeURL("/csj/ConfirmCust");
        // "Proceed to Checkout" button below table
        out.println
          ("</TABLE>\n" +
           "<FORM ACTION=\"" + confirmURL + "\">\n" +
           "<BIG><CENTER>\n" +
           "<INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"\n" +
           "       VALUE=\"Create Account\">\n" +

           "</CENTER></BIG>" +
           "</FORM>");


      out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*when I press the Submit button, I want to take the values from the form*

For this you have to do `request.getParameter("input parameter name");`

Well in your servlet you have 2 forms one having action and another does not have.

See this

```
out.println
          ("</TABLE>\n" +
           "<FORM ACTION=\"" + confirmURL + "\">\n" +
           "<BIG><CENTER>\n" +
           "<INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"\n" +
           "       VALUE=\"Create Account\">\n" +

           "</CENTER></BIG>" +
           "</FORM>");
```

here form action is present but when you press submit it calls `confirmURL` but mo values are passed(as it is not having any input parameter).

Now in this

```
out.println
          ("<Form>\n" +   
          "<CENTER>" +
            "Please Enter the following Information:\n" +

            "<TABLE border=1>" +
            "<TR>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "Customer ID: " +  
            "</TD>" +
            "<TD>" +
            "<Label>" + custId + " </Label>\n" +
 ....................
```

input parameter are present but no submit button and no form action
So no action will be performed and hence no values will be passed.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I do appreciate it. I am pretty new to JSP

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Ok no problem,you are free to ask if you have any more queries

Comment: Can I put a form action in the form with the Input parms to resubmit the same form and write the values to the file?

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel every form can at max have one action

Comment: can I just take out the form action to stay on the page and reprocess the form

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel if you remove the form action then how will you pass the data after pressing the submit button.Well using javascript also passing the values is possible.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get the data inputted in the input boxes on the form to the request object or passing them to the next JSP which will write them to the file? If I use the request.parameter(parm) ... how does that work in relation to pressing the submit button?

Comment: so, I took your advice, but something isn't right... do you still have a minute

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel yes,what is the problem now?

Comment: I am getting nulls when I use the request.parameter()

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel come to chat

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel I am weak in jquery if you can help me in jquery it will be helpful

Comment: Sure... email me, at ptrykiel@gmail.com I will do what I can to help

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel I have sent a test mail,check your inbox and please do delete all the comments that are not related to this question and answer.Unnecessary will not be useful to future users